# buttons on laptop rubber feet

Tags: laptop, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

There seems to be buttons engineered to the rubber feet of my Lenovo Thinkpad X201T laptop. I can press them with my fingernails, but there seems to be no response at all.

What are these for? (I lost my instructional manual)

Comment: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products

Comment: I downloaded a pdf and looked for it. didn't mention anything. now I'm even more confused

Comment: Could it just be that there are screw holes under the rubber feet making it look like you can "press" something but all you are doing is deforming the rubber feet?

Comment: How do you know they are actually buttons?

Comment: they give this buttony 'pop' feel when being pressed, and it produces a sound. too afraid to rip the rubber foot out..

Comment: Perhaps you could share a picture of these buttons so we can see what you are talking about.